# Do you connect light stability wires to ground nut?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I'm installing island lighting, and the instructions don't say where to connect the stability wire. We just screwed in with the green nut, along with the ground copper wire from the ceiling. Is this ok? Should we just wrap it around the mounting bracket instead?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post instructions or a photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a ground wire and should be connected to the equipment ground. If you have a metal junction box then it should also be pigtailed to the ground.

Since the fixture you have does not have a permanent mounting method and hangs by a hook, then it requires an external ground wire. Hence the bare wire.

Attaching it to the green screw is fine if you have a metal grounded box. If the box is plastic it should be wire-nutted to the bare or green equipment ground wire.

Good luck and be safe!